# Where are the mouse cursors located?

Tags: kubuntu, mouse

Which is the folder where mouse cursors are located in Kubuntu? I would like to know the full path of the folder?.

Answer (score 5):

They are located in folders in `/usr/share/icons`, named according to the theme, irrespective of the desktop environment:

```
$ ls -d /usr/share/icons/*/cursors
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors
/usr/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors
/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors
/usr/share/icons/handhelds/cursors
/usr/share/icons/redglass/cursors
/usr/share/icons/whiteglass/cursors
```